# How to read more than one line of input?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, encryption

So I have built a small basic data encrypter (for learning purposes only). It is working perfectly fine but it reads only a single line of input. Is it my Editor problem or my code have some issues.

ps: I use `CodeBlocks`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    char enc;
    int word;
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tENCRYPTOR" <<endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t---------" <<endl;
    cout << "Enter a Word: ";
    getline(cin, str);
    int n = 0;
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tENCRYPTED D@T@" <<endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t--------------\n\n" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        int randomAdd[5] = {5,6,2,3,2};
        int size = sizeof(randomAdd)/sizeof(randomAdd[0]);
//        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        word = str.at(i);
        if(i%5 == 0){
            n = 0;
        }
        enc = int(word) + randomAdd[n];
        std::cout << char(enc);
        n++;
    }

 return 0;
}
```

This works

```
Hello World
```

But I cannot enter this

```
Hello World
Have a nice day
```

because then the program exits command prompt without any error or message.

How can I read more than one line?

Comment: Is the behavior random? If this happens consistently with some input, please share that input and resulting output.

Comment: the name of the c++ header is `ctype`, `ctype.h` is the C header (actually I don't see that you are using anything from that header)

Comment: You say you input 10-15 lines, but your code can only read one line.

Comment: `enc = int(word) + randomAdd[n];` where `word == 'z'` && `n==1` leads to signed integer overflow and *Undefined Behavior*

Comment: also not the problem, but you can remove `n` and use `i % 5` instead. Makes the logic of the code simpler. Currently the code for `n` is scattered around when actually you don't need any of it

Comment: Also, take the array and the `sizeof` outside the loop.  There is no need to have those lines within the loop, since the array never changes.  Another thing -- remove commented lines -- all they do is add clutter to the post.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen no it works after I copy paste a para so how do I write multiple lines pls respond

Comment: after entering the first line (ie after you hit enter the first time) your code should continue and then finsish before you typed the second line. Is that not what happens?

Comment: A paragraph may be displayed as multiple lines in your web browser or console, but it doesn't have any newline `'\n'` characters. From the perspective of `std::getline`, it is a single line of text. The second paragraph is the second line of text, and there is nothing in your program that will call `std::getline` a second time.

Comment: turns out your actual problem is: How to read multiple lines. Then the question for you is: How is your code supposed to know when input is complete?

Comment: @ShivamJha The big question is -- why are you not debugging your code?   All of the issues pointed out could have been easily observed if you used the debugger.  You probably would have seen `getline` being called only once, that `str` contains only the first paragraph, etc.  Then any doubts, your question would be "why is getline only called once?" or "why does my string only contain the first paragraph", and not just "my program doesn't work".

Comment: what we call a "single line" can span several "lines" on display. A "single line" is text until a line break `'\n'` is encountered.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I copy pasted para from wiki so I don't know but after you comment I tried to run manually and yes after pressing enter it continues so how do I take multilinear input

Comment: i took the liberty to rephrase your question quite a bit. Please review it to check if it correctly describes your issue. If not we can roll it back

Comment: @ShivamJha Don't blindly copy and paste text from anything but a text editor, and if you do, prepare to fix the text.  When you copy/paste from some external program, website, etc. you risk picking up non-ASCII characters and other formatting artifacts.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks I got it what you are telling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  string str;
  
  while (getline(cin, str)) {
    cout << str << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code sample allows you to input multiple lines interactively from the command line/shell

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    char enc;
    int word;
    vector<string> myInput;
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tENCRYPTOR" <<endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t---------" <<endl;
    while (str != "Enigma")
    {
        cout << "Enter a line (Write Enigma to exit input): ";
        getline(cin, str);
        myInput.push_back(str);
    }
    int n = 0;
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tENCRYPTED D@T@" <<endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t--------------\n\n" << endl;
    for(auto & myInputLine : myInput)
    {
        str = myInputLine;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            int randomAdd[5] = { 5,6,2,3,2 };
            int size = sizeof(randomAdd) / sizeof(randomAdd[0]);
            word = str.at(i);
            if (i % 5 == 0) {
                n = 0;
            }
            enc = int(word) + randomAdd[n];
            std::cout << char(enc);
            n++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The input is finished if `Enigma` is written.

All input is stored in the `vector` container of the STL, see [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Afterwards, all the lines are encrypted by your algorithm.

Hope it helps?

Comment: Hey @CKE I am beginner (it has been around 15 days) and I was wondering if this code is very bad or average I would be happy if you'd respond. Thanks

Comment: @ShivamJha: Honestly I cannot judge this. I think that your algorithm is just working, but I would recommend you to write a decrypter in order to check how good your encryption is. Maybe you could also ask a friend to decrypt your output;).

Comment: @ShivamJha: Please feel free to mark this answer also as accepted (Check mark on the left side of the answer). Thanks in advance.